# mysql multiple join on same table

Tags: mysql, join, sugarcrm

I have two databases that have contacts table in each. I want to find out what contacts exists in the primary db from the redundant one. primary database is sugarcrm. the one i want to make redundant is hdb. I have the following query which is not working

```
SELECT c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name
from `sugarcrm`.`contacts` c
left join `hdb`.`contacts` as cl
    ON cl.lastname = c.last_name
left join `hdb`.`contacts` as cf
    on cf.firstname = c.first_name

limit 0, 10000
```

I have a total of 10187 records in sugacrm.contacts and total of 8619 in hdb.contatcs.

I have tried this

```
SELECT c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name
from `sugarcrm`.`contacts` c
where not exists
(select * from `hdb`.`contacts`
where firstname != first_name and lastname != last_name
)
limit 0, 10000
```

returns 14 records

I want to include comparison with email address but my query is not working. To link email address in sugarcrm is as follows

email_address table has id
email_addr_bean_rel has email id and contact id

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.first_name, 
    c.last_name
FROM `sugarcrm`.`contacts` c, `sugarcrm`.`email_addresses` e, `sugarcrm`.`email_addr_bean_rel` er
LEFT JOIN `hdb`.`contacts` as cl
    ON cl.lastname = c.last_name
    AND cl.firstname = c.first_name
    AND cl.email = e.email_address
inner join `sugarcrm`.`contacts` 
    on er.bean_id = `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.id
inner join `sugarcrm`.`email_addr_bean_rel`
    on e.id = er.email_address_id

limit 0,100000
```

I have decided to use email, Managed to get the following using navicat

```
    SELECT
sugarcrm.email_addresses.email_address
FROM
sugarcrm.contacts
INNER JOIN sugarcrm.email_addr_bean_rel ON sugarcrm.contacts.id = sugarcrm.email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id
INNER JOIN sugarcrm.email_addresses ON sugarcrm.email_addresses.id = sugarcrm.email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id
INNER JOIN hdb.contacts ON sugarcrm.email_addresses.email_address = hdb.contacts.EMAIL
LIMIT 0, 100000
```

Comment: Do you want to find out which contacts exist in both databases, or which are missing from one (or the other)?

Comment: which is missing in sugarcrm from hdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** To check what contacts are in primary and not in secondary db try this :

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.first_name, 
    c.last_name
FROM `sugarcrm`.`contacts` c
LEFT JOIN `hdb`.`contacts` as cl
    ON cl.lastname = c.last_name
    AND cl.firstname = c.first_name
WHERE
    cl.lastname IS NULL
```

But:

- you should use an id (if you have) to join not 2 string columns

**UPDATE2:** answer to "how would i change the email query to show contacts from hdb that do not exist in sugarcrm?"

```
SELECT
    hdb.*
FROM
    hdb.contacts
LEFT JOIN sugarcrm.email_addresses 
    ON sugarcrm.email_addresses.email_address = hdb.contacts.EMAIL
LEFT JOIN sugarcrm.email_addr_bean_rel 
    ON sugarcrm.email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id = sugarcrm.email_addresses.id
LEFT JOIN sugarcrm.contacts
    ON sugarcrm.contacts.id = sugarcrm.email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id
WHERE
    sugarcrm.contacts.id IS NULL
LIMIT 0, 100000
```

Comment: this returns 10894, am i on right track? If i want to do opposite i get more than 100000 records which doe snot look right

Comment: hmmm... do you have PK on firstname and lastname ? pls post the tables  structure

Comment: also how can it return 10894 rows when you said that `sugarcrm.contacts`  has 10187 rows ???

Comment: how would i change the email query to show contacts from hdb that do not exist in sugarcrm?

Comment: returns 8649 rows. does not look right if the ones that exists matches 249 and the total contacts in hdb is 8619

Comment: are you sure that the email address is unique in both contacts tables ?

Comment: there are duplicates in hdb and sugarcrm

Comment: that' the problem.. you need a unique way to identify the contacts ... and `PK AUTO_INCREMENT` is ideal

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
SELECT 
     c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name
from 
    `sugarcrm`.`contacts` c
where
     c.id in (select c1.id from `hdb`.`contacts` c1)
```

This gives records present in `sugarcrm` db

Comment: the id fields are not the same in the tables

Comment: then compare the fields which are same like `c.first_name in (select c1.first_name from `hdb`.`contacts` c1)`

Answer (score 0):

To find users in hdb that do not exist in sugarcm, try:

```
SELECT ch.id, ch.first_name, ch.last_name
from `hdb`.`contacts` ch
left join `sugarcrm`.`contacts` as cs
       ON ch.lastname = cs.last_name and cl.firstname = cs.first_name
where cs.first_name is null
```

Comment: @sharif: To ensure that only records that do not exist in sugarcm are returned - without it, this query would return all contacts in hdb, whether they exist in sugarcrm or not.